# R: How can I plot the average curve of a set of curve using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, set, average, curves

I'm relative new in R language and I'm trying to plot the average of a set of curves, for example in the picture below I have 3 curves and I need to plot the average of the 3 curves. What aproximations can I take to solve this?

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWshs.jpg)

My data is structured this way:

[All sensors are in a different data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT9Qs.jpg)

[The structure of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50qJI.jpg)

Any help is welcome and also if someone has feedback about my question is welcome too, as I'm new in stackoverflow.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data in dataframe `df`, with time down rows and Leyenda across columns:

```
df$mean <- rowMeans(df[,1:3])
```

But please do provide an example of your data in future.

Comment: Thanks, for this I need to have all the data in one data frame?

Comment: Yes for this method, look at `?cbind()` or `?merge()` to pull them into one dataframe. I think `merge()` could work best, as you have different lengths of dataframe.